# NullPointerException because of my Global Variable

Tags: java, class, global-variables

**CharacterCreator Class**

```
import java.util.*;

public class CharacterCreator {
    /*ch = character
     c = create
     g = generate
     q = question
     r = random*/
    private static Scanner in;
    private static CharacterHair chcHair;
    private static CharacterHair chgHair;

    private static String generate = "generate";
    private static String create = "create";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out
                .println("Welcome to Character Creator! How would you like to create"
                        + " your character today? Type generate or create.");
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answerHold = in.nextLine();
        if (answerHold.equals(generate)) {
            qgCharacter();
        } else if (answerHold.equals(create)) {
            qcCharacter();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    public static void qgCharacter() {
        chgHair = new CharacterHair();
        chgHair.rbodyHair();
    }
    public static void qcCharacter() {
        chcHair = new CharacterHair();
        chcHair.cbodyHair();

    }
}
```

**CharacterHair Class**

```
import java.util.*;

public class CharacterHair {

    private String[] hair;

    private Random random = new Random();
    private Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    CharacterHair() {
        this.hair = bodyHair();
    }

    public String[] getHair() {
        return this.hair;
    }

    public String[] bodyHair() {
        String[] hair = { "black", "red", "purple", "yellow", "brown",
                "orange", "blue", "blonde" };
        return hair;
    }

    public void rbodyHair() {
        int aaa = random.nextInt(hair.length);
        String pHair = hair[aaa];
        System.out.println(pHair);
    }

    public void cbodyHair() {
        System.out.println("Pick one of these: " + Arrays.toString(hair));
        String pHair = in.nextLine();
        Globe.everything[0] = pHair;
    }
}
```

**Global Variable Class**

```
public class Globe {
    public static String[] everything;

}
```

When I run this code, it is fine when I type in generate. It runs smoothly and generates a random hair color.  **But**, when I type create I am able to choose a hair color but it does not print out the hair color that I chose. When I remove the global variable from the picture the program prints out anything that I store to `pHair`. I want the program to assign the value of `pHair` to the `String[] everything`

Additional Questions:
 1. I have read about java conventions and because I am still fairly new to programming, I wanted to ask if I am following these conventions well.
 2. When I print `System.out.println("Pick one of these: " + Arrays.toString(hair));` it prints out: Pick one of these: [black, red, purple, yellow, brown, orange, blue, blonde]
Is there any way to remove the brackets?
 3. If there seems to be anything out of order or weird please tell me.

**Thank you for your time :D**

Comment: Could you paste the stacktrace ?

Comment: Sorry, but what is that?

Comment: Paste the complete error you get including the `Caused by`

Comment: @CaptainCloud A two-second Google would have answered "what is a stracktrace?". You should hone your searching skills a little, I suspect.

Comment: Sorry it was just on instinct to ask that question I understand what a stack trace is now, I just used debug mode on Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is a trivial error, you never construct an array for your everything String array!

You need `everything = new String[SOME_LENGTH];` somewhere

If you don't do this, then everything is null.

More importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). You should inspect the line carefully that throws it, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Next you will want to get rid of all "global" variables, and make most of your variables and methods non-static. Your design is broken.

Comment: *Facepalm* I can not believe what a simple error that was I was reworking the code so much I did not even realize that I had not initialized the variable! Well thank you for your help. Although, why would I make the variables non-static and get rid of the global variables? It works fine after I initialize the variable.

Comment: @CaptainCloud: some variables should be static such as constants, but most shouldn't be. If they're static, you loose all ability to unit test your code, you lose all benefits of object-oriented design. Might as well code in Fortran. It sounds as if you would benefit reading up on Object-Oriented Programming concepts especially as they apply to Java, because if you are trying to create a program without first understanding this, you're going to have a tough run with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an array that is not initialized. There is no initialization of >everything< in your code, thus resulting in a NullPointerException.